# Where does Array define the Element associated type?

Tags: swift, generics, associated-types

In Swift 2.3 where does Array define the Element associated type ?

It has to define it because it implements GeneratorType which has Element an associated Type.
Dictionary and Set both define Element but where does Array define it ?

Array has a generic type called Element, does having a generic type satisfy the GeneratorType protocol ?

I tried this out in the playground and it doesn't work out for me.

For example

```
protocol Animal{
    associatedtype Breed
}

struct Dog<Breed>: Animal{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 2, `Array` conforms to `CollectionType`, which defines the requirement:

```
/// Returns the element at the given `position`.
public subscript (position: Self.Index) -> Self.Generator.Element { get }
```

`Array` satisfies this requirement by implementing it like so:

```
public struct Array<Element> : CollectionType, MutableCollectionType, _DestructorSafeContainer {
    // ...

    // Swift can infer that Self.Index == Int & Self.Generator.Element == Element
    public subscript (index: Int) -> Element
    // ...
}
```

This allows Swift to infer that `Array`'s generic placeholder type `Element` is used to satisfy the associated type `Self.Generator.Element`, and the concrete type `Int` is used to satisfy the associated type `Self.Index`.

This takes advantage of the fact that associated types can be satisfied implicitly by the type used in the implementation of a protocol requirement in a given type that conforms to that protocol. For example, in your case:

```
protocol Animal {
    associatedtype Breed
    var breed : Breed { get }
}

// I've named the generic placeholder T to simply make clear that Swift is inferring
// T == Breed and therefore satisfying the associatedtype requirement.
// You can rename the generic placeholder back to 'Breed' – the compiler will still
// infer that it's satisfying the Breed associatedtype.
struct Dog<T> : Animal{
    let breed : T
}

enum BreedOfCat {/* ... */}

struct Cat : Animal {
    // same principle with non-generic types: BreedOfCat == Breed
    let breed : BreedOfCat
}
```

Although of course, if there are no protocol requirements that use the `associatedtype`, it'll have to be satisfied explicitly with a `typealias`:

```
protocol Animal {
    associatedtype Breed
}

struct Dog<T> : Animal{
    typealias Breed = T
}
```